# Repair SQL file or DB

Tags: php, mysql, repair

I found that my DB.sql has error shown below, i did not process it with addslashes in php so now instead of `'O\'Brien'` it is `'O''Brien'`. Making exporting and importing sql impossible.

```
(228, '', 'Sacks Cafe & Restaurant', '328 G Street', 6, 2, 7, 'NULL', 61.218929, -149.895691, '3', 1, '0'),
(229, '', 'Metroasis Advanced Training Center', '401 West Intl Airport Road Suite 1C', 6, 2, 7, 'NULL', 61.173767, -149.890884, '3', 1, '0'),
(230, '', 'Captain Cook Hotel', '4th & K', 6, 2, 7, 'NULL', 35.807266, 39.283291, '3', 1, '0'),
```

Someone know about ways to fix this it is a long file and find and replace does not work for me there should be some programs that can do it?

Dont offer online based please its not what i need.

```
"#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 281 "
```

Comment: That's standard SQL escaping for single quotes. (The backslash is just the dated approach. Should not use addslashes anyway, bla bla). Are you talking about a .sql database dump by any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd vote for writing a (simple) Perl, PHP or Python script that:

1. Reads each record (SQL select)
2. Checks for "''" in the wrong place
3. Does an update of that column for that row (SQL update)

CAVEAT:

- Make SURE to take a good backup before you run this script!